# Existence of complex integral : which theorem?

Tags: integration, complex-analysis

Consider the following complex integral :

$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-\mid p \mid y-ip\omega}dp$$
where $-\infty<x<\infty$ and $0\leq y <\infty$. I would like to compute it, so this is what I have done : 
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-\mid p \mid y-ip\omega}dp=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-\mid p \mid y}dp\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-ip\omega}dp$$
The first integral can be computed and converges but the second integral does not exists since : 
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-ip\omega}dp=\frac{i[\cos(p\omega)-i\sin(p\omega)]}{\omega}\Bigr| _{-\infty}^{\infty}$$
So my question is : what is the theorem (or theory) which states that I can't separate the integral into a product ?

Comment: What theorem tells you that the integral of  a product is  the product of the integrals? This is just nonsense.

Comment: Oh yes you are right... Sometimes we do strange things ! Thank you !